# Getting Unable to Connect error on Azure Bot

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I have an Azure Bot deployed and running on Directline channel on web page. The bot works well but leaving the bot a few mins idle, results in an error with the message "Unable to connect". I need to refresh the page to restart the bot. How can I avoid this timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-start-conversation?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) states, Direct Line connections persist for a set amount of time until they timeout. Once the connection has closed, you will need to [reconnect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-reconnect-to-conversation?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to the conversation to regain connection with the bot. Refreshing the page has a similar effect in that you are establishing a new connection with the bot.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there an event when timeout occurs so I can attempt to make a reconnect?

Comment: I don't believe there is a specific event sent proactively by the channel, but your attempt to use a timed-out connection will fail. You should therefore be able to use the information contained in the API's response to determine when you need to perform a reconnection.